# Fourier transform of matrix element of evolution operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, path-integral

I learn ''Path integrals in quantum mechanics'' by Jean Zinn-Justin now. There is a chapter about calculating the path integral for particle on a ring (rigid rotator). So, after some calculations we can obtain something about matrix element:

$$U=\left< \theta'' \right| e^{-\beta H}\left| \theta' \right> \, .$$

Here $H$ is Hamiltonian, $\theta''$ and $\theta'$ are qoordinate of the particle in final and initial moments respectively, and $\beta$ is imaginary time, which is just $\beta = i T$, where $T$ is physical time.

We know two things:

1. $U$ depends only on difference $\theta''-\theta':=\theta$
2. A set of functions $e^{i \ell\theta}/\sqrt{2 \pi}$, where $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ forms an orthonormal basis for our Hilbert space.

Then there is said in the book, that hence we can expand $U$ to Fourier series:

$$U = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\sum\limits_{\ell = -\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i \ell \theta} e^{-\beta E_{\ell}} \, .$$

It could be fine, if instead of $e^{-\beta E_{\ell}}$ it would be something like $A_{\ell}$, but here coefficients because of some reason associated with eigenvalues of Hamiltonian $E_{\ell}$! In book author writes following:

> "We have identified the coefficients of the Fourier series with the eigenvalues of $e^{- \beta H}$, because the functions $e^{i \ell\theta}/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ forms an orthonormal basis and, thus, the operator $e^{- \beta H}$ is directly diagonalized."

I completely don't understanf this move. Of course, the operator can be diagonalized, but why is it diagonal exactly in this basis? Is it correct at all?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a free-particle? I don't see how this claim can be true otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, it is free particle, but on a ring. In coordinate representation the hamiltonian of this system is $H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2 J} \partial_{\theta}^2$ It can be easy solved with stationary Schrodinger equation, but it is interesting to quantize this problem in terms of path integral.

Answer (score 1):

The "complete orthonormal basis" indicates
$$ \langle \theta | \ell\rangle= e^{i\ell \theta}/\sqrt{2\pi} ~, \\ \int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\! d\theta ~~   \langle  \ell'|  \theta  \rangle \langle \theta | \ell\rangle  /2\pi = \delta_{\ell \ell'}~,\\
\sum_\ell  \langle \theta | \ell\rangle \langle  \ell| \theta '\rangle =\delta(\theta-\theta')~.
$$
(Well, the last *δ* function is ***really a periodic*** [Dirac comb function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) $\bbox[yellow]{\operatorname{III}_{2\pi}(\theta-\theta')}$, on account of the Poisson summation formula, but let's not fuss it here, as long as you appreciate all functions of angles are periodic.)

By the [standard abuse of the Dirac notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Spinless_position%E2%80%93space_wave_function),
$$
\langle \theta | \hat L |\ell\rangle =-i\hbar \partial_\theta \langle \theta | \ell\rangle = \frac{\hbar \ell }{\sqrt{2\pi}} \langle \theta | \ell\rangle ,
$$
diagonal, so 
$$
\langle \theta | e^{-\beta \hat L ^2/2J} |\ell\rangle =e^{-\beta \hbar^2 \ell^2/2J} \langle \theta | \ell\rangle ,
$$
also diagonal, and 
$$
U=\langle \theta ''| e^{-\beta H }  
\sum_\ell  | \ell\rangle \langle  \ell| \theta'\rangle =\sum_\ell e^{-\beta \hbar^2 \ell^2/2J} e^{i\ell (\theta''-\theta')} ~/2\pi ~.
$$